# Lower version of Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, versions

So I have a 702MB disk that I'll be using, and Ubuntu 12.10 is 753MB. Any way to get an older version of Ubuntu for my disk, then upgrade later? Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

No need. Yes, the size of the iso exceeds that of the capacity of a standard CD. You can either create a live-dvd or live-usb with it. Yikes! The solution is to create a minimal cd. It downloads and installs all the missing packages after you've installed ubuntu. Follow this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) to download it. You don't need to download an old distribution, you can download a minimal cd of 12.10.

You may want to see answers for this [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/272323/114660)

Answer (score 0):

dont go for older version. just make bootable predrive using unetbootin. you will save you CD also