# Do I have to create a DVD for install or can I use a CD-R?

Tags: disk

I want to download and install 12.04.3 but the laptop I have to use does not have a DVD-R drive but has a CD-R/CD-RW drive. Can I use a standard CD to create a bootable LiveCD?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to burn Ubuntu on a CD ROM?](http://askubuntu.com/q/272323/12218) which has a solution but it is not accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You sure can. Ubuntu has done a good job of keeping their iso files small enough to fit on a standard 700MB CD. Just make sure the iso file you use is less than 700MB (Ubuntu 12.04 is about 670) and you will have no problems.

Comment: I don't believe this applies for the later versions, does it?

Comment: Correct, I believe 13.04 is the first release that won't fit on a CD. But the OP was asking about 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a CD-R cause almost all images is less then 700mb. you can create a USB STICK boot too, may be easier to you

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

you can download ubuntu directly from www.ubuntu.com/download