# Ubuntu and Xubuntu Too big for 1 CD, can you put it on 2 CDs?? How do you do that.

Tags: dvd, cd

Ubuntu and Xubuntu has gotten too big for just one CD.  I prefer to use CD not DVD. Many older machine do not have DVD capability or not USB bootable.  So how can I get Ubuntu on several CDs.  Is there some way to do this???  Will Ubuntu make a both CD and DVD iso options??

Comment: Did you read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) ?

Comment: Does this http://askubuntu.com/questions/303083/does-the-ubuntu-13-04-disk-image-fit-on-a-cd/303086#303086, help?

Comment: You can also use plob as described in a similar post to your's here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/272323/is-there-a-way-to-burn-ubuntu-on-a-cd-rom

As a simple answer to your question: it seems to be impossible (without a lot of work/trouble) to burn the ~800+ MB xubuntu installation to a 700mb cd but workarounds exist.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an alternative: the official **Ubuntu Minimal CD, that weights only 30mb**  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD#A32-bit_PC_.28x86.29

This particular officially supported image is really small, and will download the data required to perform the installation (instead of having it within the CD). **The ISO is really light weights at most 30Mb (~25Mb for standard machines) so you won't have the size problem to burn it in a CD**. Of course, the counter is that **you must be connected to internet in order to perform the install**. Also notice that for Ubuntu's older than 13.04 this .iso can only be burned in a CD, and won't boot from an USB stick.

Last, **this is a "flavor" of the alternate install**, that means **no  graphical interphase** (no fancy windows taking you smoothly through the install process). It is an old-school (windows xp like) installer. If you have doubts on how to proceed witht his install, I recommend you to run in another machine a full-featured live ISO since the steps and the sequence are very similar, and seeing the dialogs and such in parallel may help you for the first time. Good luck!